# mixing of promise in observable within auth guard

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am trying to return a true or false within an promise(gameid) inside an observable that returns me if the user is logged in or not:

here my authguard:

```
//Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
//Rxjs
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
//Services
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public loginService: LoginService
  ){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.loginService.getAuthenticated().pipe(map(user => {
      if(user && user.hasOwnProperty('uid') && user.uid != "" ) {
        this.loginService.getGameIdUser().then( game => {
          if(game.hasOwnProperty["gameid"] && game.gameid != "") {
            return true; // <-- this return is reached but doesnt effect my route
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['selgame']);
            return false;
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }
    }))
  }
}
```

it seems the return true does not effect the authguard.. where is my mistake?

Comment: It's because when you run the promise, the code continues and completes your canActivate() and the promise runs later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. You'll turn your promise into an observable.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        public router: Router,
        public loginService: LoginService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.loginService.getAuthenticated().pipe(concatMap((user) => {
            if (user && user.hasOwnProperty("uid") && user.uid != "") {
                return from(this.loginService.getGameIdUser()).pipe( // <-- Turn your promise to an observable
                    map((game) => {
                        if (game.hasOwnProperty.gameid && game.gameid != "") {
                            return true; // <-- this return is reached but doesnt effect my route
                        } else {
                            this.router.navigate(["selgame"]);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }),
                );
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(["login"]);
                return of(false);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now it says that type Observable<unknown> can not match with Observable<boolean>

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer. Since we are using concatMap I have to return an observable, instead of just false, on the else portion.

Comment: hmm sorry its still the same... i tried to fix it on my own but i think i still dont understand it :(

Comment: ahh okay the missing part was that i am using rxjs6 and i had to change it to ```return observableOf(false);```